# In R how to divide range equally when values same multiple times

Tags: r

I am having following data frame.

```
data <- data.frame(unit= c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2), 
               val= c(100,200,300,1200,1200,1200,1200,2000,100,100,100,1000,1100), 
               fin = c(100,200,300,525,750,975,1200,2000,100,400,700,1000,1100))
```

As, 1200 came 4 times then step size = (upper limit-lower limit)/count(same value). 
When consecutive values appear(column -"val") multiple times with respect to column "unit" then divide that range equally between those values. The expected output should be like column "fin".

Comment: The logic for dividing the val is not clear.  How did you decide to start with 525?

Comment: As, 1200 came 4 times then (1200-300/4)=225 step size..So, 300+225=525

Comment: OK. So `fin` is the same as `val`, except that when there are consecutive values of `val` which are the same (say `X`), `fin` goes up in steps. What is the "lower limit"? Is it the highest value beneath `X`? Can we assume that `val` is sorted within each unit?

Comment: Could you also explain what the "upper limit" is?

Comment: -@dash2. You assumed correct. val is sorted in ascending order. lower limit = highest value beneath x, upper limit = x value, length = count of x value appeared n times

Answer (score 0):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), create two columns of 'lag' and 'lead' values of 'val' ('val1', 'val2') grouped by 'unit'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, c('val1', 'val2') :=  .(shift(val), shift(val, type = "lead")), .(unit)]
```

Get the row index (`.I`) where the number of rows is greater than 1 (`.N > 1`) grouped by 'unit' and the run-length-id (`rleid`) of 'val'.

```
i1 <- data[, .I[.N > 1], .(unit, grp = rleid(val))]$V1
```

Using the grouping variable as above, and specifying the `i` as 'i1', we check if the first element of 'val1' is `NA`, in that case, create a sequence from the first element of 'val1' increment `by` the difference of first elemets of 'val' and 'val1' divided by number of rows or `else` get the sequence from the first element of 'val' increment `by` the difference of last element of 'val2' with first element of 'val' divided by number of elements

```
data[i1, val := if(!is.na(val1[1])) seq(val1[1], length.out = .N+1, 
     by = (val[1]- val1[1])/.N)[-1] else  seq(val[1], length.out = .N, 
        by = (val2[.N] - val[1])/.N) , .(unit, grp = rleid(val))]
data[, c('val1', 'val2') := NULL][]
#    unit  val  fin
# 1:    1  100  100
# 2:    1  200  200
# 3:    1  300  300
# 4:    1  525  525
# 5:    1  750  750
# 6:    1  975  975
# 7:    1 1200 1200
# 8:    1 2000 2000
# 9:    2  100  100
#10:    2  400  400
#11:    2  700  700
#12:    2 1000 1000
#13:    2 1100 1100
```